# Why isn't my Emoji-mart loaded properly in this code?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a button that, when clicked, shows an emoji panel. If I click select one emoji, the panel disappears and the button is replaced with the selected emoji. 
 When I click on that emoji, the emoji panel shows up again and the same process can be repeated.
 Below is the code I wrote, using EmojiMart CDN. In the console, I can see the `emojiPicker` printed properly when I click on the button, but **nothing shows up on the screen.** The emoji panel is supposed to show up. 
What do you think is the problem with my code?

```js
const emojiPicker = new EmojiMart.Picker({
    emojiSize: 24,
    title: 'Pick an emoji',
    onSelect: (emoji) => {
        const emojiButton = document.getElementById('emoji-button');
        emojiButton.innerHTML = emoji.native;
        emojiPicker.hidePicker();
    },
});

function showPicker() {
    console.log("showPicker called");
    if (emojiPicker.picker) {
        emojiPicker.pickerVisible = true;
        emojiPicker.picker.classList.add("visible");
    }
}

function hidePicker() {
    console.log("hidePicker called");
    emojiPicker.pickerVisible = false;
    emojiPicker.picker.classList.remove("visible");
}


const emojiButton = document.getElementById('emoji-button');
    emojiButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("showPicker called");
    console.log(emojiPicker)
    showPicker();
});

function appendPicker() {
    if (emojiPicker.picker) {
        document.body.appendChild(emojiPicker.picker);
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => appendPicker(), 100);
    }
}

appendPicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-mart@latest/css/emoji-mart.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-mart@latest/dist/browser.js"></script>

<button id="emoji-button"></button>
```

Comment: you may need React to make this lib work

Comment: @underflow Oh what if I don't? Is it impossible to use the library without using React? I'm using Django, and using plain JavaScript with template tag.